# Is there a way to change DownloadManager.Request method to "POST"?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

In my application, I am trying to use [DownloadManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) for downloading a file. For that, I have to create an instance of [DownloadManager.Request](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html) and enqueue it in the DownloadManager using [DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.Request request)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html#enqueue(android.app.DownloadManager.Request)) method. But I need to set RequestMethod of the **request** as **POST**. Is there a way to do that?

I'm looking for a method similar to [HttpURLConnection.setRequestMethod(String method)](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#setRequestMethod(java.lang.String)) for DownloadManager.Request.

Comment: why would you ever need a POST request to download something? That's conceptually wrong

Comment: Yes. I knew that Tim. But I need a solution for time being.

Comment: there is no solution: see [here](http://aosp.opersys.com/xref/android-7.1.2_r33/xref/packages/providers/DownloadProvider/src/com/android/providers/downloads/DownloadThread.java#442) - you have to use default GET method